# Rspec tests not running because of initializer Yaml files

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, yaml

I'm integrating tests with Rspec into quite a large / developed app. When I run the test I'm getting very odd errors from some of my initializers.

For example, my `carrierwave.rb` loads a yaml file, when I run the test command I get:

```
carrierwave.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

which is referring to the second line of code below:

```
fog_config = YAML::load_file(Rails.root.join 'config/fog.yml')[Rails.env.to_s]
config.fog_directory = fog_config['directory']
```

Momentarily if I remove that line of code in carrierwave, omniauth starts to complain too:

```
omniauth.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Again, another yaml file:

```
  fb_config = YAML::load_file(Rails.root.join 'config/fb_app_version.yml')[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
```

I'm guessing the solution is to change my yaml files or include something in the tests, but I'm not sure what. Any ideas would be most appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to include `test` entries in the Yaml files in question.

For example, your `config/fog.yml` probably looks something like this:

```yaml
production:
  directory: the_prod_directory
  other_keys: ...

development:
  directory: the_dev_directory
  other_keys: ...
```

You need to add a `test` key:

```
test:
  directory: the_test_dir
  other_keys: appropriate values
```